# return nth match from string using regex

Tags: regex, tableau-api, regex-lookarounds, data-cleaning

I am using Tableau to create a visualization and need to apply Regex to string values in my data set. I'm trying to use Regex to return the nth match of this string of data: b29f3b2f2b2f3b3f1r2f3+b3x#. The data will always be in one line and I need to break the data out into substrings each time the characters b,s,f, or d are encountered and I need to match the nth occurrence returned. For example, when identifying which number match to return the following will match:

- n=1 matches b29
- n=2 matches f3
- n=3 matches b2
- n=4 matches f2
- n=5 matches b2
- n=6 matches f3
- n=7 matches b3
- n=8 matches f1r2
- n=9 matches f3+
- n=10 matches b3x#

I can get the n=1 match to return the proper value using bfsd(?=[bfsd]) and have tried to get the subsequent values to return using lookahead, but can't find a regex which works. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why should `f1r2` be a matching term, but not `b29f3`?  How do we know to take one letter/number and not two (or three) of them?

Comment: matching terms should always begin with only b, f, s, or d characters. any other alphanumeric characters are included in the string

Comment: So, your item pattern is `[bfsd][^bfsd]*`. You may use `^(?:.*?([bfsd][^bfsd]*)){n}` to get what you need. `^(?:.*?([bfsd][^bfsd]*)){2}`  will get you the 2nd one. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oXfIXX/1).

Comment: Wiktor - this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Why it is tagged in Tableau?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your item pattern is `[bfsd][^bfsd]*`.

You may use `^(?:.*?([bfsd][^bfsd]*)){n}` to get what you need, just update the `n` variable with the number you need to get.

This pattern will get you the second value:

```js
^(?:.*?([bfsd][^bfsd]*)){2}
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oXfIXX/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:.*?([bfsd][^bfsd]*)){2}` - two occurrences of

  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, as few as possible
  - `([bfsd][^bfsd]*)` - `b`, `f`, `s` or `d` followed with 0+ chars othet than `b`, `f`, `s` and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
[bsfd][^bsfd]*
```

Use the `'global'` flag.

This  will create matches that start with one of the four letters, followed by any number of other characters.

The result will be an `array` with all the matches. Note the `Array` will start with `index 0` (not 1).

Comment: Thanks Poul, this does make the appropriate matches, but how do I write the expression to return a specific match (e.g. the 5th match only) and not all the matches?

Comment: You call the matches with an index like matches[0].

Answer (score 0):

if you have `gawk`, this will partition the input field as your spec

```
$ awk -v FPAT='[a-f][0-9rx#+]+' '{$1=$1}1'

$ echo "b29f3b2f2b2f3b3f1r2f3+b3x#" | 
  awk -v FPAT='[a-f][0-9rx#+]+' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i " -> " $i}'


1 -> b29
2 -> f3
3 -> b2
4 -> f2
5 -> b2
6 -> f3
7 -> b3
8 -> f1r2
9 -> f3+
10 -> b3x#
```

Comment: Thanks Karakfa, but I don't use gawk